# Secure Webservice works in JDev 11.1.1.2 (WL Server 10.3.2) but not in JDev 11.1.1.6 (WL Server 10.3.5)

Tags: java, web-services, security, ssl, weblogic

We have a secure webservice that works in JDev 11.1.1.2, using the Weblogic.jar v10.3.2. But does not work in JDev 11.1.1.6, using Weblogic.jar v10.3.5. If I swap the weblogic.jar used by JDev 11.1.1.6 to the older weblogic.jar, the service works properly. Per what I've read from the Oracle documentation, there should be no changes needed to existing webservice code between the two iterations of the weblogic.jar. Any ideas?

**The error received is:**

aused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: [Security:090542]Certificate chain received from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx --> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx was not trusted causing SSL handshake failure. Check the certificate chain to determine if it should be trusted or not. If it should be trusted, then update the client trusted CA configuration to trust the CA certificate that signed the peer certificate chain. If you are connecting to a WLS server that is using demo certificates (the default WLS server behavior), and you want this client to trust demo certificates, then specify -Dweblogic.security.TrustKeyStore=DemoTrust on the command line for this client.
    at com.certicom.tls.interfaceimpl.TLSConnectionImpl.fireException(Unknown Source)

**Specifying 'DemoTrust' does not work. Nor does adding the certificate to the CA trust store. Upon adding to the CA trust store, I receive this error:**

javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: [Security:090482]BAD_CERTIFICATE alert was received from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx. Check the peer to determine why it rejected the certificate chain (trusted CA configuration, hostname verification). SSL debug tracing may be required to determine the exact reason the certificate was rejected.
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.readResponseCodeAndMessage(HttpClientTransport.java:218)

Comment: We are consuming this webservice and do not have administrative access to the end-point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are Certicom SSL changes between those 2 versions of Weblogic (introduced in 10.3.3). There are also changes in the validation of certs. It's not surprising that your service is not working with the new jar file. As a general rule, just make sure to use the same version of weblogic.jar as the server itself is running. Refer to:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13754/compat.htm#BEHCJGFB

Comment: Thanks for the information, it'll give me another avenue to research. The problem is we have it running along side a second web service that requires the upgrade to implement new security features required by our Oracle DRM server. I could strip that web service from the project and move it into it's own, but our production environment is being upgraded to the newer version of Weblogic sometime in January.